# java jTable : how to know the row number?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, renderer

I wrote a class that implements TableCellRenderer, since I want to put checkboxes inside the jTable.
In the getTableCellRendererComponent method of this class, i have the condition :

if(isSelected){ do ..... }

inside this if condition, how can I know the row number ?

code :

```
 private static class ValueRenderer extends JCheckBox
    implements TableCellRenderer {

    private static final Color hilite = new Color(0xE8E8E8);

    public ValueRenderer() {
        this.setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        Value v = (Value) value;
        this.setSelected(v.selected);

        if(isSelected)
        {
            if(v.selected==true)
            System.out.println("checked"); 
            else System.out.println("unchecked");
        }
        return this;
    }
}

  private static class Value {
    private Boolean selected;

    public Value(Boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;

    }



}
```

Comment: just use `row` it is in the signature of the method so it should be available

Comment: I didnt notice this, thanks for your help !

Comment: be careful doing that. This way you will be forced to use a single renderer for all row values under the same column.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you creating a Value class and a custom renderer? From the code it is just a Boolean. Just add the Boolean directly to the TableModel and then override the getColumnClass() method of the JTable or TableModel to return Boolean and the table will use the default Boolean renderer.

Read the JTable API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on How to Use Tables for an example that uses Booleans.

Answer (score 0):

Use the row parameter passed to your renderer.  It's zero based just like arrays in Java.